# Can't ssh to cygwin in a domain from Linux and Mac

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, cygwin, samba

Following [this](https://microtechnology-services.github.io/2016/04/29/cygwin-sshd-on-windows-domain.html) page I successfully configured Cygwin sshd in a Windows 10 computer running as a member of a Windows(Samba) domain.

I can ssh to that machine from a Windows 10 inside the domain and from a Windows 10 outside the domain. I am running the ssh command in Cygwin in both cases.

But, I can't connect from a Linux Debian 10 machine outside the domain, I can't connect from the Linux Debian 10 running the Samba DC, I can't connect from a Mac outside the domain.

Any ideas?

I use always the same command to start the connection `ssh nicola@domus`, the same in each OS. I attach the last part of what I see in the attempt to connect via Linux.

```
$> ssh -vvv nicola@domus
...
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/p/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/p/.ssh/known_hosts:76
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.16.3.53
debug1: Host 'domus' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/p/.ssh/known_hosts:75
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/p/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:hcDASnV1vvd88xpKM/xN2XtUSCvcW3oPUz0izqFMTBE
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/p/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/p/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/p/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/p/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/p/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:hcDASnV1vvd88xpKM/xN2XtUSCvcW3oPUz0izqFMTBE
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 172.16.3.53 port 22
```

Comment: Does your sshd log gives any error messages ?

Comment: `/var/log/cygsshd` is empty. Do you know any other file I could look into?

Comment: When you start cygwin sshd, can you give any options ? like `-d` in Linux for debugging.

Comment: I can, but if i run it directly from a user the story takes a very different direction. I can log into other machines where it works like that. FYI i post you what happens if i run as an administrator `sshd -d`, and try to log in as a normal user. see [here](https://pastebin.com/V8bdu4Ef)

Comment: I found [this](https://www.softwareab.net/wordpress/cygwin-sshd-pubkey-authentication/) post which gives some interesting hints. Still, it is not the domain case. I will try to investigate more tomorrow.

Comment: Public key athentication does not work, from Linux, Mac and also Wiindows. There are several posts about that, but no one specific on the domain case AFAIgoogled.

Comment: You need to debug on server side, to see why it refused connection.

Comment: I wish I knew how to `strace` this;)

Comment: `strace` may not be useful in your situation.

Comment: I found where i can see error messages. Windows Event Viewer. There I see this `sshd: PID 1118: fatal: seteuid 1049679: No such device or address`. But, `1049679` is 'nicola' ID in `/etc/passwd` ! I tried with other users, same error type.

Answer (score 0):

I found just after posting that I can actually connect via Linux and Mac if I force password authentication.

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no nicola@domus
```

But, I consider this more a quick fix than a solution. Do you have any better ideas?